# Did Khidr kill a minor or an adult?

Tags: tafseer

> So they proceeded until they came across a boy, and the man killed
> him. Moses protested, “Have you killed an innocent soul, who killed no
> one? You have certainly done a horrible thing.”

When I initially encountered this, I assumed the boy was a minor; however, in English 'boy' can also refer to a relatively young man.

Answer (score 1):

In the Arabic original it says "until they came across a Ghulam", Ghulam usually refers to a young boy in Arabic, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghulam.

This question was discussed in Qortoby's tafsir of the same ayah:

> And "ghulam", Ulama had argued whether he was an adult or not. Hisham ibn al-Kalbi said that he was an adult and he used to one of the bandits where he lived [..], however, the majority of Ulama say that he was not an adult since the word Ghulam is used to indicate man who did not reach puberty. [..] Ibn Abbas mentioned that he was a bandist teenager. Ibn Jubayr said that he was in the [takleef](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803101937768) age.

Answer (score 1):

Ghulam may refer to a boy or a young adolescent/teenager beyond the age where they are supposed to take responsability for their deeds. However, Moses qualified him as زَكِيًّا , "pure". This ceartainly refers to a small boy who is completely in the learning process an not supposed to be responsible.

Answer (score 1):

The exegetes differ on this.

The majority of them held that the boy was a child and was killed because he would grow up to be a disbeliever and Khidr knew this through revelation from Allah.

> وإن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم لم يكن يقتل الصبيان فلا تقتل الصبيان إلا أن تكون تعلم ما علم الخضر من الصبي الذي قتل ‏.‏ وزاد إسحاق في حديثه عن حاتم وتميز المؤمن فتقتل الكافر وتدع المؤمن
>
> [Najda (the leader of the Khawarij) wrote a letter to Ibn Abbas seeking fatwa on some questions. Ibn Abbas replied:]
>
> "The Messenger of Allah ﷺ did not kill children, so do not kill children, unless you know what Al-Khidr knew about the child whom he killed."
>
> Ishaq added in his Hadith from Hatim: " ... and you can tell who is a believer, in which case kill the disbeliever and leave the believer"
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1812b)</sup>

This stance is also argued from the wording of the verse:

> قال أقتلت نفسا زكية
>
> [Moses] said, "Have you killed a pure soul ... ?"
>
> <sup>— [Quran 18:74](https://quran.com/18/74?translations=20)</sup>

As Moses عليه السلام would not call him innocent based on mere assumption, rather he would probably have said that when he saw that the boy was physically a minor, as any acts of a minor are not recorded and hence they are known to be innocent\pure:

> رفع القلم عن ثلاثة عن النائم حتى يستيقظ وعن **الصبي حتى يحتلم** وعن المجنون حتى يعقل
>
> The pen has been lifted from three: a sleeper till he awakes, **a boy till he reaches puberty**, and a lunatic till he comes to reason.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/53)</sup>

Some however held that the boy was an adult. An argument for this being the wording of the verse:

> بغير نفس
>
> for other than [having killed] a soul?
>
> <sup>— [Quran 18:74](https://quran.com/18/74?translations=20)</sup>

A minor can not be killed even if he had committed murder, as he is not accountable for his actions. Hence mentioning this would serve no real purpose unless he was an adult who could have been killed for committing murder. This indicates that Moses عليه السلام  perceived him as an adult.

Some have also argued based on the recitation\tafsir of the verse:

> وأما الغلام فكان أبواه مؤمنين (وكان كافرا) فخشينا أن يرهقهما طغيانا وكفرا
>
> And as for the boy, his parents were believers (and he was a disbeliever), and we feared that he would overburden them by transgression and disbelief.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 18:80](https://quran.com/18/80?translations=20) ,  [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4726)</sup>

As the boy has been called a disbeliever while a minor is not considered a disbeliever, especially when his parents are believers.

Ref:  [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura18-aya74.html#qortobi)